# Find out when the date was changed

Tags: linux, datetime

On a Linux system, is there any way to find out when the system date was last changed?

I am running a process that is sensitive to date changes and I need to detect the case where the user has changed the date while the process was running. Does the Linux kernel record this information, or can this be detected in any other way?

Comment: hmm..., detection-wise some `x=$(date +%s); sleep(1); y=$(date +%s); ((y-x-1 > tolerance)) && echo "profit";` run in a `while true` loop would do?

Comment: Perhaps, although I don't know beforehand how long does it take for the process to complete. It would be great if there was some sort of `uptime` reporting time elapsed since last date change (actually since last `settimeofday` call)...

Comment: Look into *all* system logs in `/var/log` and subdirectories. What you're looking for is a noticeable leap in timestamps. That will take a lot of manual effort and will not give you the exact moment when the date got changed, but it will give you an estimate and a range for that.

Comment: Are you running auditd? Is it configured to log privileged actions, such as system time changes? If necessary you could put a heartbeat timestamp, say once a minute, and see if there's a discontinuity in that record.

Comment: I'm afraid no auditd..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution for this (other than using a patched kernel, which I wanted to avoid).

Since in my particular case all date changes occur through the `date` command, I finally implemented a solution that was good enough for my particular needs, which was to place a `date` shell script early in the path which would basically set a "date changed" flag and then call the actual `date` binary:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch /tmp/date.changed
/bin/date "$@"
```

However I am not happy with this and would be very interested if someone comes up with a better solution.